# MSVCR100D.dll missing when running Allegro project in debug

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, allegro, allegro5

I have Allegro 5 set up with VS2012 on Windows 8 and am trying to compile the sample code from the Allegro wiki.  I have installed VC++ 2010 Redist. (both x86 and x64) and I am able to build/run the project in release just fine.

The issue is that when trying to run it in debug it crashes complaining that MSVCR100D.dll is missing.  It was my understanding that the non-debug and debug versions of this dll should be included with VC++ 2010?  Any ideas on how to fix this other than just downloading the dll from somewhere and dropping it in manually?

Comment: No, it is not included.  If you would deploy it, you'll be running a program that uses more than one version of the runtime.  Which is a Really Good Way to crash your program without having any idea why.  Recompile everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess that you are using a binary package of Allegro built for VC++ 2010 (v10). You should be using the ones for 2012 (v11) or compile from source by yourself. Mixing runtimes is not advisable.

Allegro 5.0.8 is the first to have binaries for v11 and while normally they would be up at http://www.allegro.cc/files, they currently are only available at [the release announcement thread](https://www.allegro.cc/forums/thread/611458/970499#target).